# Migration from ZF2 to ZF 3 without getServicelocator();

Tags: php, zend-framework2, migration, zend-framework3

I am new at ZF3 and I need your help.
In ZF3 there is no service Locator any more. So I created a Factory class to replace the service Locator in my code.

Here is my code with service Locator in my AbstractController.php file:

```
protected function getService()
{
    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get($service); //remove from ZF3
    return $this->service = $service;
}
```

Now I replaced the service Locator in AbstractController.php:

```
protected function getService($service)
{
    $service = $this->service;
    return $this->service = $service;
}
```

And in Module.Config.php I added the following lines:

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\AbstactController::class => Controller\AbstactControllerFactory::class,
        ],
],
```

And I created a AbstractControllerFactory file with the following lines:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Application\Controller\AbstractController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

    class AbstractControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
    {
        protected function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
        {
            return new AbstractController($container->get(service::class));
        }
    }
```

I need to know if this is a correct migration from ZF2 to ZF3?

Comment: There is no service locator because it is a bad practice to use it outside of factories. You shouldn't try to reproduce how it work, you should understand how to get the same behavior without using it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

Ok I understand, but is the idea behind my code correct?

Comment: As I see it is correct. But it would be better to remove getService() as you don't need it anymore. You inject $service in constructor and assign it to the Controller. Later in Controller you can just use $this->service

Comment: Could you please post your factory example as an answer and accept it so this question could be marked as answered.

Comment: You mean me? @Xerkus

Answer (score 1):

In ZF3 the first thing you do is create your Service and a Factory for it. Let's take in this example UserManager.php in Services folder.

So we have in folder **Service** -> **UserManager.php** and in **Service** -> **Factory** -> **UserManagerFactory.php**

**UserManagerFactory.php:**

```
<?php
namespace User\Service\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Service\UserManager;

/**
 * This is the factory class for UserManager service. The purpose of the factory
 * is to instantiate the service and pass it dependencies (inject dependencies).
 */
class UserManagerFactory
{
    /**
     * This method creates the UserManager service and returns its instance. 
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {        
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        return new UserManager($entityManager);
    }
}
```

**UserManager.php:**

```
<?php
namespace User\Service;

use User\Entity\User;

/**
 * This service is responsible for adding/editing users
 * and changing user password.
 */
class UserManager
{
    /**
     * Doctrine entity manager.
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;  

    /**
     * Constructs the service.
     */
    public function __construct($entityManager) 
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

// REST OF YOUR CODE

}
```

Now that we have our service, we go into **User\config\modules.config.php**:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        Service\UserManager::class => Service\Factory\UserManagerFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Well that's basically it, we can inject the service in our controller and job done:

```
<?php
namespace User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

/**
 * This controller is responsible for user management (adding, editing, 
 * viewing users and changing user's password).
 */
class UserController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    /**
     * User manager.
     * @var User\Service\UserManager 
     */
    private $userManager;

    /**
     * Constructor. 
     */
    public function __construct($userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

   // REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

I really hope this helps you understand how to use Service in ZF3.

Good Luck!